# Data driven with nodejs using excel spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, data-driven-tests

I am doing some research for my work place. The plan is to use javascript (as we have people that know this) through nodejs. We will also be using selenium with this and visual studio for writing the code.

I have some basic tests running with everything working.

What I would like to know is how can I do data driven tests in java script that pull the data form excel sheets. We could have 8-10 columns per row and up to 30 rows of data for each test. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I have done a little research but anything I find is c# or normal java. Unsure of best addons to use in this scenario as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are excel-reading [npm modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs).  Short of that, you could just save as CSV and there are a number of [CSV-reading and writing modules](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=csv) as well.

I'm not sure if you've seen it, but there's also [mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha) and [chai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai), which are great for testing.

So the general architecture I'd use would be to write some mocha tests which read in the data from the excel or CSV file and then run tests using that data as input. Something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
var parse = require('csv-parse');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

var csvData=[];

describe('When using some test data', () => {
  before((done) => {
     s.createReadStream(req.file.path)
      .pipe(parse({delimiter: ':'}))
      .on('data', function(csvrow) {
        csvData.push(csvrow);        
      })
      .on('end',function() {
        done();
      });
  });
  it ('should be able to pass a test with all data', () => {
    csvData.forEach((datum) => {
       // not sure what you're testing for, but check for each to pass here.
       expect(datum).to.not.be.a('null');
    });
  });
});
```

Note, I didn't test the above, but that's in the ballpark of how you'd approach things.

If whatever method you're testing requires a callback, you can either use async/await semantics or else use the `it('test description', (done) => {});` callback syntax like I did with the `before` call.

Comment: Thank you for that and I will have a look at mocha/chai. I think I understand what you have done above. How could you specify different columns in the sheet? For instance say I have three columns 'username', 'password', 'ID'. I want it to read that row and then save each item on that row as a variable. Once it gets to the end of the test it repeats the test using the next rows data. Sorry if my knowledge is not great as its fairly new to me.

Comment: It'll depend on which CSV or Excel module you pick, but most of them assume or allow you to specify that the first row is the 'headers' and then each item in the JS array is an object that looks like, `{ header1: 'item1', header2: 'item2' }` and so on.  Or to use your example, if the first row has contents 'ID', 'username', 'password', then the array would look like `[ { 'ID': '1233', 'username': 'bob', 'password': 'I am sooper s3cr3t' }]`